# \pdfpageheight does not work in XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, paper-size

The XeTeX reference manual says that  this engine understands `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth`.  However, is seems to ignore the requests to change paper size in the middle of the document.  Consider this example (from https://www.tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb32-3/tb102veytsman-ebooks.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyshi,lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\textheight500cm
\pdfpageheight500cm
\EveryShipout{\pdfpageheight=\pagetotal
\advance\pdfpageheight by 2in
\advance\pdfpageheight by 2\topmargin
\advance\pdfpageheight by \footskip
\advance\pdfpageheight by \textheight
\advance\pdfpageheight by -\pagegoal}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[3-5]
\pagebreak

This line has a footnote\footnote{\lipsum[6-8]}.
\lipsum[1]

And this line too\footnote{\lipsum[12]}.
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

1. `pdflatex` produces two pages with different page heights as intended.
2. `lualatex` also works fine
3. `xelatex` (`XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011)`, `xdvipdfmx-0.7.8`) produces two pages of the same height (letter), which is *not* what I wanted.

My questions:

1. Is this a bug in `xetex` or, possibly, in `xdvipdfmx`, or maybe I do something wrong?
2. Are there any workarounds - for example, using PostScript `\special`s instead of `\pdfpageheight`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What a complicated example ;-).

As default the both lengths have the value 0pt in xetex. If you change only one xetex will ignore it and fall back to the default. So you should also set `\pdfpagewidth` then it will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\showthe\pdfpagewidth
\showthe\pdfpageheight
\begin{document}
\pdfpageheight10cm
\pdfpagewidth5cm
abc
\newpage
\pdfpageheight5cm
\pdfpagewidth15cm
cde
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I would consider this a bug: XeTeX manual says about compatibility with pdftex, and this behavior is not compatible.  Still, your solution works great.  By the way, the example was not contrived: people asked for this feature for e-book formatting - please see our paper.