# How to create \pagebreak-like command that actually "breaks'' the page?

Tags: page-breaking, paper-size

I want to create a `\pagebreak` variant that reduces the page (in which the `\pagebreak` was made) size so that there's NO (besides bottom margin) blank space after the page break. Is that even possible (the output could have pages of different size each)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/14)

Comment: See the code listed in this post. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40911/pdfpageheight-does-not-work-in-xetex If you use XeTeX, the answer to that post is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the post referenced by GregH I found that pasting the followings line into preamble is *almost* what I wanted:

```
\usepackage{everyshi}
\pagestyle{empty}
\textheight500cm
\pdfpageheight500cm
\EveryShipout{\pdfpageheight=\pagetotal
\advance\pdfpageheight by 2in
\advance\pdfpageheight by 2\topmargin
\advance\pdfpageheight by \footskip
\advance\pdfpageheight by \textheight
\advance\pdfpageheight by -\pagegoal}
```

It seems to work well when `\documentclass` is **article** (although I wouldn't use the default `\textheight` of 500cm), but it doesn't work for **amsart**: for instance everything between a `\[small|med|big]skip` and the next \pagebreak is cutted off; moreover, some items on `itemize`/`enumerate` environments are also cutted.

So, I guess it might be usefull for some, I'm still looking for a way that at least works with amsart..